# Passing Class type as a parameter

Tags: java

I have two methods like this

```
public void updateA (Object obj) throws CommonException
{
  if ( !(obj instanceof A) )
  {
     throw new CommonException(obj);
  }
  // other codes  
}


public void updateB (Object obj) throws CommonException
{
  if ( !(obj instanceof B) )
  {
     throw new CommonException(obj);
  }
  // other codes  
}
```

Now I want to extract the instance checking part into a separate method.
Is it possible to do as follows?

```
public void chkInstance (Object obj, Class classType) throws CommonException
{
  if ( !(obj instanceof classType) )
  {
     throw new CommonException(obj);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also just attempt to cast it to the `classType` that you want it to be - if it's not an instance of one an exception will be thrown. It won't be a `CommonException`, it'll be a `ClassCastException`, but could you catch this in a higher order class?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Class.isInstance`:

```
if(!(classType.isInstance(obj)) {
    // ...
}
```

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) actually flat-out states (emphasis mine):

> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class. **This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator**.

Comment: Thank you Martel. But how can I call this method? Like this? : chkInstance (obj, A.class); ?