# C# Passing a class type as a parameter

Tags: c#, oop, interface

This for C#? 
[Passing Class type as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8265241/684646)

I have a class adapter that implements an Interface. I want to fill an array structure with MyFooClass instances where MyFooClass's name or reference I want to receive it from outside. I'll instantiate them inside my adapter code.

For example:

```
    public void FillWsvcStructs(DataSet ds, ClassType Baz)
    {
        IFoo.Request = ds.DataTable[0].Request;
        IFoo.Modulebq = string.Empty;
        IFoo.Clasific = string.Empty;
        IFoo.Asignadoa = ds.DataTable[0].Referer;
        IFoo.Solicita = "Jean Paul Goitier";


        // Go with sub-Elems (Also "Interfaceated")
        foreach (DataSet.DataTableRow ar in ds.DataTable[1])
        {
            if ((int) ar.StatusOT != (int)Props.StatusOT.NotOT)
            {
                ///From HERE!
                IElemRequest req = new (Baz)(); // I don't know how to do it here
                ///To HERE!

                req.Id = string.Empty;
                req.Type = string.Empty;
                req.Num = string.Empty;
                req.Message = string.Empty;
                req.Trkorr = ar[1];
                TRequest.Add(req);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There was an answer that stated to use `.ToThisType()` and `.ToTheOtherType()` having thesame class controlling what it would get..., because in some point the class you are using knows what should she get there. It was quite useful too. a pity I cant Upvote since it was deleted. However now u know that solution also exists. Thanks, _unsung hero_!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379564.aspx) and [their constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) should do what you want, I believe:

```
public void FillWsvcStructs<ClassType>(DataSet ds) where ClassType : IElemRequest, new()
{
    IFoo.Request = ds.DataTable[0].Request;
    IFoo.Modulebq = string.Empty;
    IFoo.Clasific = string.Empty;
    IFoo.Asignadoa = ds.DataTable[0].Referer;
    IFoo.Solicita = "Jean Paul Goitier";


    // Go with sub-Elems (Also "Interfaceated")
    foreach (DataSet.DataTableRow ar in ds.DataTable[1])
    {
        if ((int) ar.StatusOT != (int)Props.StatusOT.NotOT)
        {
            IElemRequest req = new ClassType();

            req.Id = string.Empty;
            req.Type = string.Empty;
            req.Num = string.Empty;
            req.Message = string.Empty;
            req.Trkorr = ar[1];
            TRequest.Add(req);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there are more than 1 interface typed elems to instantiate?  `public void FillWsvcStructs<TBaz, TBar, TQux>` How should I declare it?

Comment: You got it chief! `public void FillWsvcStructs<TBaz, TBar, TQux>(DataSet ds) where TBaz: IElemRequest, new() where TBar: TElemRequest, new() where Qux : IElemRequest, new()`

Answer (score 6):

That's probably best solved by using generics:

```
public void FillWsvcStructs<T>(DataSet ds) where T : IElemRequest, new()
{
   //..
   //new() constraint enables using default constructor     
   IElemRequest req = new T(); 
   //IElemRequest constraint enables using interface properties
   req.Id = string.Empty;
   //..
 }
```

If you have multiple types that you need to be able to access/instantiate, the declaration follows the same rules (as may easily be gathered from msdn):

```
public void FillWsvcStructs<T, U, V>() where T : IElemRequest, new() 
                                       where U : IFoo, new()
                                       where V : IBar, new()
{

    //..
}
```

Comment: What if there are more than 1 interface typed elems to instantiate?  `public void FillWsvcStructs<TBaz, TBar, TQux>` How should I declare it?

Answer (score 4):

I think you want [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379564%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Declare your method like this:

```
public void FillWsvcStructs<T>(DataSet ds)
    where T : IElemRequest, new()
{
    //You can then do
    IElemRequest req = new T();

}
```

The [`new()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) constraint requires `T` to have a public parameterless constructor, and the `IElemRequest` constraint ensures it implements `IElemRequest`.

Comment: What if there are more than 1 interface typed elems to instantiate?  `public void FillWsvcStructs<TBaz, TBar, TQux>` How should I declare it?

Answer (score 3):

You need a [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
public void FillWsvcStructs<TBaz>(DataSet ds) where TBaz : IElementRequest, new()
{
    // ...
    IElementRequest req = new TBaz();
    // ...
}
```

The generic constraint ("`where...`") enforces that the type you pass in implements the `IElementRequest` interface and that it has a parameter-less constructor.

Assuming you had a class `Baz` similar to this:

```
public class Baz : IElementRequest
{
    public Baz()
    {
    }
}
```

You would invoke this method like so:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
FillWsvcStructs<Baz>(ds);
```

---

#### Addendum

Multiple, different, generic type parameters can each have there own type constraint:

```
public void FillWsvcStructs<TFoo, TBar, TBaz>(DataSet ds) 
    where TFoo : IFoo, new()
    where TBar : IBar, new()
    where TBaz : IElementRequest, new()
{
    // ...
    IFoo foo = new TFoo();
    IBar bar = new TBar();
    IElementRequest req = new TBaz();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What if there are more than 1 interface typed elems to instantiate?  `public void FillWsvcStructs<TBaz, TBar, TQux>` How should I declare it?

Comment: You can add as many type constraints as you have type parameters. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx).

`IElemRequest req = (IElemRequest) Activator.CreateInstance(Baz);`

If the type that `Baz` represents has a constructor that takes parameters, the complexity of that will grow (as you'll have to use Reflection or dynamic calls to make it work).  If `Baz` doesn't represent a type that inherits from `IElemRequest`, you will get an ugly runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

The method:

```
public void FillWsvcStructs<T>(DataSet ds) where T : IElemRequest, new() {
    ...
    IElemRequest req = new T();
    ...
}
```

Calling the method:

```
FillWsvcStructs<Bez>(ds);
```

Comment: What if there are more than 1 interface typed elems to instantiate?  `public void FillWsvcStructs<TBaz, TBar, TQux>` How should I declare it?

Comment: FillWsvcStructs<T, U, V>(DataSet ds) where T : IElemRequest, new()  where U : IElemRequest, new() where V : IElemRequest, new() {}